# Issue after reverting a branch in git

Tags: git, github

I have two branches one is master and another is xyz.
In xyz I have added new features. Mistakenly I merged xyz into master after realizing I have done a mistake I reverted xyz from master.
Now on my local system from xyz branch when I take pull from master to xyz my xyz branch becomes replica of master and all new features/file belonging to this branch become unavailable

Comment: Please be specific when you say "revert". Do you mean reset or revert?

Comment: "Mistakenly I merged xyz into master after realizing I have done a mistake I reverted xyz from master" -> You'd have to elaborate a bit on this part. *Which commands* did you do here?

Comment: I used "Revert" button from github.com after pull request

Comment: [This doc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) explains in-depth reverting reverts & friends.

Comment: Basically you need to revert the reverted merge in the xyz branch.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected. Merging a revert from master into xyz performs that revert on xyz.

I'll demonstrate. Let's say we have this:

```
A B C (master)
   \
    X Y Z (xyz)
```

We merge xyz into master and then revert the merge commit:

```
A B C --- M - REVERT (master)
   \     /
    X Y Z (xyz)
```

Now if you pull master into xyz, you are asking for a merge. What is a merge? It's an enactment of all the changes on both sides since the point where the two branches were most recently in common. And what is that point? It's Z!

So the contributions on both sides since Z are:

- Master: revert everything that X, Y, and Z did
- Xyz: nothing

So, since xyz has no contribution to make to this merge, the outcome of the merge is that only the changes from master happen — meaning that everything that X, Y, and Z did is undone on xyz, just as you say.